# AWS: Find IAM user creator

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is it possible to find out who created an IAM user? I have a bunch of users in my organisation AWS account which I want to remove but I'd like to check with the ones that created them if they are still needed for any reason but I can't find the creator information.

Is it possible to get that detail either through console (couldn't find it) or programmatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to use CloudTrail.

Go to the service CloudTrail -> Event History -> Then change filter to Resource Type, and under resource type enter 'User'

You can do this through the console too if you want to filter or handle larger data sets.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudtrail/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You may need to select N.Virginia as your region for Event History as IAM users are created globally and therefore their related events get associated with N. Virginia region.